# Angular Google Maps : fit="true" recenters to show infowindow

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

- I have used angular google map to display multiple markers and used fit="true" to display all the markers in single view.
- But on zooming to a particular marker, on clicking the marker, the map zooms out to default fitted center to display the infoWindow instead of showing the infoWindow at the zoomed in position itself.
- Code Snippet (This is the part of the page where I have defined google map not entire code):

```html
<ui-gmap-google-map center="mapView.viewPort.center" zoom="mapView.viewPort.zoom" options="mapView.options">

                                <ui-gmap-markers fit="true" models="mapView.markers.notes" coords="'self'" idkey="'id'" doCluster="true" clusterOptions={maxZoom:20,averageCenter:true,styles:[{url:'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/images/m5.png',height:90,width:90},]} icon="'icon'">
                                    <ui-gmap-windows templateUrl="'template'" templateParameter="'templateParam'">
                                    </ui-gmap-windows>
                                </ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

- The mapView.markers.notes contains a json array consisting of information related to each note such as id, contents, etc.
- I have tried this without using fit="true" and it works perfectly but I also want the map to adjust to view all the markers in first view so I need to use fit="true" also.

Comment: your snippet doesn't work, and your controller would be nice to see what `mapView.markers.notes` actually contains

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have updated the question accordingly, am sorry can't give the entire code. But need help badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got solved by using an older version of angular google maps, it was an issue of version above 2.1.3 wherein it doesn't properly support more details in icon attribute than url. 
I have raised an issue corresponding to this on github, the url is:

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1785